# How to change the Attribute background color in css code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used following code and I want to replace the old color when I click next menu.

Please give me the solution. How to replace the old color when i click next option.

HTML CODE:

```
    <head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function ChangeColor(obj) {
         obj.style.backgroundColor = "#bfcbd6";
      }
</script>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
    <li class="topmenu"><a onclick="ChangeColor(this);"  href="#" title="Home" style="width:154px;" >Home <span class="numberend">1</span> </a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a onclick="ChangeColor(this);" href="#" title="Product info" style="width:154px;"><span>Product info</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Please check following link: http://jsfiddle.net/8JwhZ/1058/

Comment: Dude, you're opening a `<head>` tag inside a `body` tag, and you're not even closing it! Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: If I click the any one option the color should be change and replace the old color when I click next options. but I dont know how to replace the color?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8JwhZ/1058/

Comment: Your html still sucks, [revise it properly](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/page-structure).

Comment: pls check this http://jsfiddle.net/8JwhZ/1058/

Comment: you can do it with css `a:active {background-color: #bfcbd6}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your post, you have exaple on jsfidle.

You can use something like this :

```
  </head>
  <script>
   $('.menu').click(
      function(){
         $(this).css("background","#bfcbd6")
      }
    )

  </script>
  <body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
      <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" title="Home" class="menu" style="width:154px;" >Home <span class="numberend">1</span> </a></li>
      <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" class="menu" title="Product info" style="width:154px;"><span>Product info</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7F7BP/1/

Comment: Can you answer this :    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860173/sorting-not-enable-in-my-table

Answer (score 0):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/T3WML/)

```js
function ChangeColor(obj) {
    /* Set all the link colors back to the original one */
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.topmenu a');
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].style.backgroundColor = "#005984";
    }
    /* Set the color of the selected one */
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "#bfcbd6";
}
```

Comment: how to change the font color to black while selecting?

Comment: Text color can be set using `yourElement.style.color="#000"`

Comment: You really should try first, but whatever.. [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5bFkG/)

Comment: can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860173/sorting-not-enable-in-my-table